# iOS CoreBluetooth centralManager:willRestoreState: won't be call if scanning and connecting while app been killed

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, restore, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an iOS App which act as CoreBluetooth central role and interact with a BLE device. I found a strange behavior while opt in CoreBluetooth's restoration feature.

Tested on iOS 9.2(13C75) / iPhone5

1. <*As Expected*> While app been killed during scanning peripheral, `centralManager:willRestoreState:` will be invoke when peripheral discovered.

   ```
   // Scanning
   [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[MY_SERVICE_UUID] options:nil];

   // Kill
   kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);

   // centralManager:willRestoreState: return with dictionary when MY_SERVICE_UUID peripheral appear in range
   @{ kCBRestoredScanServices = ( MY_SERVICE_UUID ) };
   ```
2. <*As Expected*> While app been killed during connecting peripheral or has a active connected peripheral, `centralManager:willRestoreState:` will be invoke when that connecting/connected peripheral appear.

   ```
   // Scanning
   [centralManager connectPeripheral:A_CBPERIPHERAL options:nil];

   // Kill
   kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);

   // centralManager:willRestoreState: return with dictionary when MY_SERVICE_UUID peripheral appear in range
   @{ kCBRestoredPeripherals = (
     "<CBPeripheral: 0x14da2d70, identifier = 6C32ADB6-C531-0250-050B-B14F4429BECE, name = MY_NAME, state = connecting>"
   )};
   ```
3. <strike><***NOT*** As Expected> While app been killed during connecting peripheral or has a active connected peripheral **AND** also scanning at the same time, `centralManager:willRestoreState:` will **ONLY** be invoke when that connecting/connected peripheral appear and app will not be awaken by non-connecting but desired scanning peripheral. which I don't know why and can't find any info from Apple document.</strike>

   > **Update 01/14/2016**: I found that there is a small error in my other part of apps which cause the problem. now everything work as expected. I'll keep the old post for whom may interested in.

   <*As Expected*> While app been killed during connecting peripheral or has a active connected peripheral **AND** also scanning at the same time, `centralManager:willRestoreState:` will be invoke when that connecting/connected peripheral appear and app will also be awaken by non-connecting but desired scanning peripheral.

   ```
   // Scanning and Connecting
   [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[MY_SERVICE_UUID] options:nil];
   [centralManager connectPeripheral:A_CBPERIPHERAL options:nil];

   // Kill
   kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);

   // centralManager:willRestoreState: return with dictionary when MY_SERVICE_UUID peripheral appear in range
   @{ kCBRestoredPeripherals = (
     "<CBPeripheral: 0x14da2d70, identifier = 6C32ADB6-C531-0250-050B-B14F4429BECE, name = MY_NAME, state = connecting>",
      kCBRestoredScanServices = ( MY_SERVICE_UUID )
   )};
   ```

Note:

- All my scanning/connecting/connected peripheral have same service with UUID MY_SERVICE_UUID
- Above kill code are just for demonstration time sequence, I usually put kill code at `applicationDidEnterBackground:` which can kill the app as soon as I press home button.

I'm curious about what I found and just want to know is there anybody also facing the same issues.